# Arrow shaped lines from one point (char) to another

Tags: arrows

Can anyone tell me how I can do (*if possible*) in LaTeX, something similar to what I show in the image? (I mean the arrow-shaped lines with arrowhead). Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is surely a duplicate, however, this is a way to achieve what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\mynode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt](#1){$#2$};}}
\begin{document}
    blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah
    \[
    \mynode{fromhere}{2}\cdot(\mynode{toherea}{4}x^{2}+\mynode{tohereb}{3}x-\mynode{toherec}{6})= 8x^{2}+6x-12
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \foreach \mytarget in {a,b,c}
        \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2pt]fromhere.south) to [out=-90,in=-140] ([yshift=-2pt]tohere\mytarget.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{6pt}

    blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Emilio You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer! Next time please remember to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: @Emilio Bravo! :)